# Is Nbsp in CDATA valid

Tags: xml, cdata

This might be a stupid question. Whether it make sense to have non breaking space in XML like this?

```
<someElement><![CDATA[Hello.&nbsp; Is it me you looking for?.]]></someElement>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would argue it makes sense in the way that without CDATA, `&nbsp;` would be complained as undefined entity, which in turn makes the XML document considered not well-formed. Whether the `&nbsp;` would be rendered properly as non-breaking space depends entirely on the party that receives the XML later.